# java program to read all text and eliminating whitespace and line

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

i want to write a java program to read all the text from a file but without whitespace and lines..suppose given below is all text from a file now i want to read this text and copy it to other file

```
 var provinfo={"cdn":"//bluehost-
 cdn.com","domain":"xyz.com","name":"xyz","phone":["(888) 401-4678","(801) 

 765-9400"],"code":"bh"};

 provinfo.cdn = location.protocol + provinfo.cdn;
```

such that the resultant text in new file is like

```
varprovinfo{"cdn":"//bluehostcdn.com","domain":"xyz.com","name":"xyz","phone["(888)401-4678","(801)765-9400"],"code":"bh"};provinfo.cdn=location.protocol+provinfo.cdn;
```

as you can see the text is merged into single line by eliminating whitespace and lines. Thats what i want.

```
scanner = new Scanner(new File("D://actual.txt"));
String a = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
String b= a.replaceAll(" ", "");
String c = b.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+\\s+", "");
System.out.println(c);
```

I used this code for writing on console but using the same with fileouputstream does not working?

Comment: what have you tried? at least show us that you know how to read and write to file

Comment: Read char by char and do not put the whitespace characters in your StringBuilder?

Comment: scanner = new Scanner(new File("D://actual.txt"));
  String a = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
  String b= a.replaceAll(" ", ""); 
  String c = b.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+\\s+", "");
  System.out.println(c);        i used this code for writing on console but using the same with fileouputstream does not working..????

Comment: edit your question... and paste it there

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate the whitespace there is a very useful and overlooked function

```
yourString.trim()
```

However, it wont elimante the lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while (scanner.hasNext())
        {
            stringBuilder.append(scanner.next().replaceAll("\\s", "").replaceAll("\n", ""));
        }

        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working absolutely fine !!! with your above program.

```
    File outputFile = new File("output.txt");
    outputFile.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    fileOutputStream.write(c.getBytes());
    fileOutputStream.close();

    // read again from disk to make sure
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File(outputFile.getAbsolutePath()));
    System.out.println(scanner1.next());
```

output :

```
varprovinfo={"cdn":"//bluehost-cdn.com","domain":"xyz.com","name":"xyz","phone":["(888)401-4678","(801)765-9400"],"code":"bh"};provinfo.cdn=location.protocol+provinfo.cdn;
```

Comment: where is the file named "actual.txt" from which i need to read..??

Comment: @roanjain this is extension of your code. Read the file as you do in the question, and after that write to a file.